Is there a way to protect my global routes in laravel?
I have two different user roles ( admin, sales-admin)
I have created a middleware for each of them to see different views, and it works perfectly.
on the other hand, I have some public routes everyone can access them
how it's working now:when I login as sales-admin I can see my views + global routes as a logged sales user
what I want is: when I login as sales-admin be able to see my views (www.mywebsite.com.salesadmin) which is working ✔️+ if sales-admin hits a public URL like(www.mywebsite.com) make them logout then be able to see the public routes

That's an odd request, but instead of roles you can consider using different guards to authenticate admins and sales-admins. Then in the corresponding admin routes you'd use auth:admin or auth:sales-admin to check authentication and your users will never be authenticated on the default guard

I have come up with an approach by creating another middleware to redirect the sales admin to his URL (www.mywebsite.com.salesadmin) whenever he hits the root URL
I think that one is simpler @apokryfos

Why would you want to log people out to see the public routes? If logged in users cannot see public routes then there is probably something wrong with the routes instead.

I have a system for selling tickets online - everyone can buy it
and salesadmin can buy for people
Public routes are for everyone
and salesadmin can buy for people with his own link
Is the goal clear?

If you don't mind blocking your admins from accessing public content then that's a perfectly fine solution. Adding a guard allows your admins to access your public site as though they are public users but is indeed more complex to implement.

You can use a middleware.
App\Http\Middleware\BlockRoles.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlockRoles
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$blockedRoles)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        // TODO your custom logic to retrieve user role
        $userRole = $user?->getRole();

        // If role is in the block list
        if (in_array($userRole, $blockedRoles)) {
          // Logout
          Auth::logout();

          // Redirect to login page 
          redirect()->route('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

App\Http\Kernel.php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ...

    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        ...,
        'block' => BlockRoles::class,
    ];
}

routes/web.php
Route::middleware(['block:sales-admin'])->group(function () {
  // TODO your global routes here...
});

